Late 90s/Early 00s Art/Maze book - Full pages of highly intricate sci-fi/fantasy illustrations
I was obsessed with these as a child. I found them in a local library (UK) around 15-18 years ago and they're certainly discontinued today; the books are definitely gone.
I remember each page was full of incredibly intricate fantasy scenes of lost, abandoned worlds, spaceships, ancient civilisations etc. All in a sort of 'maze' or isometric format possibly? Absolutely crammed full of tiny people and passageways and things happening. Think Escher but x1000 and with much more colour. This was most likely an art/illustration book.
ChatGPT & Perplexity have yielded nothing useful or close so far despite many suggestions.
Weirdly enough Stephen Biesty's Cross-Sections is the closest I could find in terms of intricate art style but still a world away from what I'm looking for.

Are the National Geographic Maze Adventure books like "Storming a Castle" the right general style? https://www.amazon.com/Storming-Castle-National-Geographic-Adventures/dp/0792269403 That one looks slightly Escher-esque but it also looks like it's more tightly themed than the variety you described.

@PeterDeGlopper that seems to be on the right track in terms of style, however it looks like a much more simplified/child friendly version of what I'm looking for. AI wasn't able to suggest this book so I'm wondering how much else its missing...

LLM-powered chatbots are not a good source of actual information. Although I don't know this one either.

A long shot, but this reminds me of Maze by Christopher Manson. Probably not the one, but if you enjoyed those books you might enjoy this one.
